# Writeable byte stream style functionality in C#

Tags: c#, binary, floating-point, compression, arrays

I need to build a stream of bytes, by writing `int` and `float`/`double` data into it. How do I easily accomplish this in C#? I'm aware of the method to get the raw bytes of a float variable, but does C# already have a byte-stream writing system that I could easily leverage?

Reading a float value from a bytearray:

```
uint floatBytes = .. // read 4 float bytes from byte[] array
float floatVal = *((float*)&floatBytes);
```

Writing a float value into bytearray:

```
float floatVal = ... // read a float from the float[] array
uint floatBytes = *((uint*)&floatVal);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> does C# already have a byte-stream writing system that I could easily leverage?

The .NET library has a pair of stream-decorators for this, BinaryWriter and BinaryReader.

```
var reader = new BinaryReader(someStream);
float f1 = reader.ReadSingle();   // Single == float
double d1 = reader.ReadDouble();
string s1 = reader.ReadString();  // the Writer issues a length-prefix.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx) and [BinaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx)